# logstash geo_point error elk latitude must be a number

Tags: elasticsearch, type-conversion, geolocation, typeerror, elk

I have created my index pattern to map my csv file(geoLocation in geo_point)

```
PUT _template/geotemplate
{
"index_patterns": [
      "flightgeolocation"
    ],
"settings" : {},
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "geolocation" : {
          "type" : "geo_point"
        }
      }
    },
"aliases": {}
}
```

I updated my config file and I have made latitude and longitude in float type and put them as a new field (geLocation)

```
    input { stdin{} }
    
    
    filter {
        csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => 
        ["Airport_ID","Name","City","Country","IATA",
        "ICAO","Latitude","Longitude","Altitude","Timezone","DST",
        "database_time_zone","Type","Source"]
     
    }
 mutate {convert => ["Airport_ID", "string"] }
 mutate {convert => ["Name", "string"] }
 mutate {convert => ["City", "string"] }
 mutate {convert => ["Country", "string"] }
 mutate {convert => ["IATA", "string"] }
 mutate {convert => ["ICAO", "string"] }
 mutate {convert => ["Latitude", "float"] }
 mutate {convert => ["Longitude", "float"] }
 mutate {convert => ["Altitude", "string"] }
 mutate {convert => ["Timezone", "string"] }
 mutate {convert => ["DST", "string"] }
 mutate {convert => ["database_time_zone", "string"] }
 mutate {convert => ["Type", "string"] }
 mutate {convert => ["Source", "string"] }
 mutate {
     add_field => {
        "geoLocation" => "%{Latitude},%{Longitude}"
    }
}
}

output {
   elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "flight"
   }
   
   stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

But I always have the same error :

```
Guinea,GKA,AYGA,6.081689834590001,145.391998291,5282,10,U,PacificPort_Moresby,airport,OurAirports[2021-05-02T19:45:35,275][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main][6f6097aabf7327a68ae97015b3ece31fcdcae152465b7ff4d6cd4d72dc9e602d] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"flight", :routing=>nil, :_type=>"_doc"}, #<LogStash::Event:0x6001a384>], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"flight", "_type"=>"_doc", "_id"=>"qWovLnkBE-V7VJ24f7oA", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", **"reason"=>"failed to parse field [geoLocation] of type [geo_point]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"parse_exception", "reason"=>"latitude must be a number"}**}}}}
```

That say that latitude must be a number but that's a number.

Comment: Can you share an example of the message you are trying to ingest? The one in the error is not complete, it does not have all the columns.

Comment: One issue is that according to your mapping the field should be named `geolocation` and not `geoLocation` (i.e. all lowercase)